# how to expand a keyval argument

Tags: pdfpages, key-value, arguments

I'm trying to expand a value for an argument which will be the range of pages included in the document, but I can't figure out how to do that. 
At first, I was getting

> ERROR: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

The MWE is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\myargval}{1-3}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-3, clip]{example.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=\myargval, clip]{example.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The commenters explained how to use \edef & \noexpand to evaluate the value of the argument.

However, in a full version, I'm also having another argument `pagecommand` which should not be expanded:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\myargval}{1-3}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-3, clip, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}}]{example.pdf}
\edef\temp{\noexpand\includepdf[pages=\myargval, clip, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}}]{example.pdf}}\temp

\end{document}
```

If I use that, I get:

> ERROR: Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 10.

Comment: `\edef\temp{\noexpand\includepdf[pages=\myargval, clip]{example.pdf}}`

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, it compiles correctly but doesn't include any page :(

Comment: @VitomirKovanovic: That should be `\edef\temp{\noexpand\includepdf[pages=\myargval, clip]{example.pdf}}\temp`

Comment: Oh, I see! And now I understand how it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following trick to expand what you need, and keep things that shouldn't expand unexpanded by prepending it with `\noexpand`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcommand{\myargval}{1-3}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-3, clip, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}}]{lipsum50}

\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
        \noexpand\includepdf[pages=\myargval,
                             clip,
                             pagecommand={\noexpand\thispagestyle{headings}}]
                            {lipsum50}}\x

\end{document}
```

The addition of a group in the general form

```
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup <stuff>}\x
```

ensures that `\x` is doesn't survive. This is not necessary, but `\x` may be defined as something different before this use (in general), which is restores its meaning after calling `\x`. `\edef` expands whatever is expandable (`\endgroup` is not) while `\noexpand\<csname>` expands to `\<csname>`.

<sub>`lipsum50.pdf` is a minimal document counting `\lipsum[1-50]` from the [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

A complicated solution, but the final interface is cleaner.

I didn't provide support for all the keys, it should be clear how to augment the set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xincludepdf}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { xincludepdf } { #1 }
  \xincludepdf_include:Vn \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xincludepdf_include:nn
 {
  \includepdf[#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xincludepdf_include:nn { V }

\tl_new:N \l_xincludepdf_options_tl

\keys_define:nn { xincludepdf }
 {
  % pagecommand must not be expanded
  pagecommand .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nn \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { pagecommand=#1, },
  % all others should be fully expanded
  pages .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { pages=#1, },
  nup   .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { nup=#1, },
  landscape .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { landscape=#1 },
  landscape .default:n = true,
  delta .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { delta=#1, },
  offset .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { offset=#1, },
  frame .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { frame=#1, },
  frame .default:n = true,
  column .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { column=#1, },
  column .default:n = true,
  columnstrict .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { columnstrict=#1, },
  columnstrict .default:n = true,
  openright .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { openright=#1, },
  openright .default:n = true,
  clip .code:n = \tl_put_right:Nx \l_xincludepdf_options_tl { clip=#1, },
  clip .default:n = true,
  % ...
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\myargval}{1-3}

\begin{document}

\section{Whatever}

\xincludepdf[pages=\myargval,clip, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{headings}}]{kant}

\newcommand{\tpsh}{\thispagestyle{headings}}

\xincludepdf[pages=\myargval,clip, pagecommand=\tpsh]{kant}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a key=value interface that comes with that feature built in (I'd recommend `expkv`, but I'm its author... Other packages that have some expansion-control support built in are `pgfkeys` and `options`. Adding a wrapper around an existing macro that uses other key=value parsers is easiest with `expkv`.).

Unfortunately you want to use it for an existing macro that already uses another key=value interface, so we have to augment this one a bit (similar to @egreg's answer, but much simpler here). To do so we use `\ekvparse` (it'll apply the rules described below), and rebuild the key=value list afterwards with two auxiliary macros (`\xincludepdf@k` and `\xincludepdf@kv` in the following).

`expkv` provides a mechanism to specify expansions of key-values in a simple way. Just prefix your key with `<rules>:`  (including the space after the colon) and the rules will get executed (in a key=value-pair the rules apply to value, if no =value was given they apply to the key). The following rules are built in (in the 2023-01-23 release):

- `o` expand the value once
- `e` fully expand the value using `\expanded`
- `c` build a macro from the provided value (using `\csname`)
- `f` expand the value until an unexpandable token is hit (if that's a space the space is removed)
- `V` the value should be a single token, expands that token to the value (if it's a macro this is in effect `o`, if it's a register will result in that register's contents)
- `v` like doing `c` and `V` (but different result if the resulting macro was undefined)
- `s` strips one set of surrounding spaces and (if afterwards around everything) braces
- `b` adds one set of braces around the value
- `p{<stuff>}` places `<stuff>` before the value
- `P{<stuff>}` places `<stuff>` after the value
- `g` gobbles the first token or brace-group of value
- `\r` reinsert the result of all expansions as additional key=value input
- `\key{<rules>}` in a key=value pair apply  to the key instead of the value
- `R` same as `V\r`
- `r` same as `v\r`

Multiple rules are consecutively applied from left to right, exception to this is `\r` that'll always apply after all other rules are processed.

For this use case we only need the `o`-rule (or could use the `V`-rule instead).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{expkv}

\newcommand{\myargval}{1-3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\xincludepdf[2][]
  {%
    \expandafter\includepdf
      % inner \expanded fully expands \ekvparse,
      % outer \expanded fully expands all \xincludepdf@k(v)
      \expanded{\expanded{[\ekvparse\xincludepdf@k\xincludepdf@kv{#1}]}}%
      {#2}%
  }
% needs to protect against the outer \expanded, so uses \unexpanded (we don't
% want to expand more than the explicitly stated rules need)
\newcommand\xincludepdf@k[1]{,\unexpanded{#1}}
% the space between the = and the value make this more robust for most key=value
% parsers
\newcommand\xincludepdf@kv[2]{,\unexpanded{#1= {#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=1-3, clip]{example-image-duck.pdf}
% o: means expand the value once, the space after the colon is mandatory
\xincludepdf[o: pages=\myargval, clip]{example-image-duck.pdf}
\end{document}
```

The `\ekvparse` doesn't need to know any of the keys of `\includepdf`, it'll just handle your requested expansion, every other parsing is handled by `\includepdf` itself, that'll complain if it encounters an unknown key.