# Passing arguments using pgfkeys to a macro for including PDF files, using pdfpages

Tags: expansion, pdfpages, pgfkeys

This is a slightly simplified version of a macro I've been writing (using `pgfkeys` and `pdfpages`) to include PDF files.

This seems to be working.

I ran into one bump. `includepdf` does not like it when I try to pass a macro as a argument to the `pages` argument. I implemented a workaround I found in [Werner's answer to the question "how to expand a keyval argument"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362161/3406), which is about the same issue. I left out Werner's usage of groups, which I thought was unnecessary, and made things more complicated. I initially thought that I could use the `pgfkeys` `.expand once` handler to work around this, but this doesn't seem to be possible outside PGF/TikZ. For some magical reason this seems to be possible inside PGF/TikZ, I don't know why.

1. I'm not really familiar with `pgfkeys` or any TeX key-value package,
   for that matter. So suggestions for improvements with respect to my
   `pgfkeys` usage would be much appreciated.
2. Without the workaround implemented (i.e. passing a macro directly to
   the `pages` argument of `includepdf`) I get the same error as
   [Vitomir
   Kovanovic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3413/nickolay-kolev)
   does in that question, namely:

   ```
   ERROR: Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
   ```

   but this only happens when `-` or `,` is passed as part of the
   argument to `pages`, not otherwise. I'm just wondering why this
   error only occurs in that case. Is there any simple reason why?
3. Also, is there any other or better workaround for this expansion
   issue than the one I used? In particular, does `pgfkeys` offer any
   workarounds using the `.expand once` handler, or otherwise?
4. This one is a bit more vague, but why does the `.expand once`
   handler even work in PGF/TikZ? It somehow expands the argument
   before passing that, but how does it manage to do that when regular
   TeX can't do it? I'm very unclear what is going on.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

 \pgfkeys
{
  /pdffile/.is family, /pdffile,
  % Calling the keys so that the macros are still defined if 
  % arguments are not passed.
  default/.style =
  {
    captioning=false,
    blankpage=false,
    cappos,
    cap,
    pagenum
  },
  captioning/.is if=hascaptioning,
  blankpage/.is if=hasblankpage,
  cappos/.default = {(7,-4)},
  pagenum/.default = {1-},
  cappos/.estore in = \cappos,
  cap/.estore in = \cap,
  pagenum/.estore in = \pagenum,
}

% #1 optional argument, used to pass list of keys from pgfkeys
% #2 filename
\NewDocumentCommand{\pdffile}{o m}
{
  \newif\ifhasgrid
  \newif\ifhascaptioning
  \newif\ifhasblankpage
  \pgfkeys{/pdffile, cap/.default = #2}
  \pgfkeys{/pdffile, default, #1}%

  \edef\tempx{\noexpand\includepdf[pagecommand=
    {
      \unexpanded{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
          % Add caption
          \ifhascaptioning
          \node [font=\bfseries, align=center] at \cappos{\cap};
          \else\fi
        \end{tikzpicture}}
    }
    ,pages=\pagenum]{#2}}
  \tempx
  % Add blank page
  \ifhasblankpage
  \clearpage \phantom{} \clearpage
  \else\fi
}

\begin{document}

\pdffile[captioning, cap=FOOBAR, cappos={(7,1)}, pagenum=2-3]{foo.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example is to complicated. Reduce it to the problem.

Comment: `\catcode`_=12` is not only a bad idea, but you don't even make use of it.

Comment: @HenriMenke I use it, just not in this example. I have names (usually files) with underscores, and it's a nuisance dealing with that. I wasn't planning on including any maths in here, and egreg wrote an answer saying he thought it was harmless if one wasn't going to doing subscripting. See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359804/3406. Was there some other reason I don't know about? In any case, I've now removed it from the example.

Comment: @FaheemMitha `pgfkeys` uses `\scantokens` in some places and when you set a key containing `_` with catcode 12 but the catcode is different when fetching the key, everything will blow up.

Comment: @HenriMenke I see. Very interesting. In that case, please do write an answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/359787/3406, because that isn't generally known. Is the `underscore` page safe for this `pgfkeys` usage, then?

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, the `underscore` package is actually worse, because it makes `_` active which is problematic not only in `pgfkeys` but also everywhere else.

Comment: you don't need to change the catcode to handle file names. The internal code should normally always catch this case.

Comment: I get no error with your code (I replaced foo.pdf by  `example-image-a4-numbered.pdf`).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I recall, it doesn't. To be clear, I'm talking about filenames with underscores. Nothing more exotic. I suppose I could work up a test example if anyone cares.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer There aren't any errors. My questions are asking for explanations, not fixes. Particularly in the area of expansion, where there are many mysteries. Especially with how `pgfkeys` handles it. PGF experts, explanations would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HenriMenke Ok, in that case, again, please write an answer, and mention that that the `underscore` doesn't cut it either. People should be educated on the issues.

Comment: Sorry your question is rather incomprehensible. You have a number of keys and it is quite unclear which one is the work-around and for what and what is actually your (main) problem. Try to make a more concise example and better stick to one question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The workaround is the temporary macro beginning with `\edef\tempx`, which is then called by `\tempx`. You can compare it to Werner's answer, it's the same idea. I could break this up further, but since the questions are all interrelated, I though it easier to just make one post. And again, I don't currently have a problem, but would like some explanations. And the example is relatively long because I'm using a number of different `pgfkeys` techniques, and it takes some space.

Comment: you do not need to do anything special about filenames with underscores, they work by default.

Answer (score 3):

Well if I got it right the core problem is that `\includepdf` doesn't handle `pages=\mypages` well if `\mypages` is a range. Imho the correct solution to this problem is to write the author of pdfpages and ask him that he adds the necessary code to expand the value once. E.g. along this lines:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\define@key{pdfpages}{pages}{%
 \AM@CheckValue{pages}{#1}%
 \expandafter\def\expandafter\AM@pagestemp\expandafter{#1}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\mypages{1-4}
\includepdf[pages=\mypages]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively I would define a new pdfpages key, e.g. `pageso` which does this expansion. I would not use the \edef\next method here, that looks overcomplicated.

Comment: "Alternatively I would define a new pdfpages key, e.g. pageso which does this expansion." Could that be user-defined, using `pgfkeys` or otherwise, or would it need to be part of `pdfpages`? If the former, an illustrative example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Simply take the definekey above and replace pages by pageso.

Comment: Interesting approach, but this would approach would require understanding each package well enough to make such changes. In any case, changing `pages` to `pageso` in the definekey did not work for me.

Comment: well you then naturally should also use the new key. But imho the best is to write the author that he expands.

Comment: Yes, I did use the new key as well. I changed your code in three places. Namely, the `\define@key` line, the `\AM@CheckValue` line, and in the argument to `\includepdf`. I also tried different variations. I wasn't sure about what the `\AM@CheckValue` line was for, but it doesn't work even if I don't; change that line. See if it works for you. I did write to the author already, asking him to add that feature.