# Oddities when passing a macro to the pages argument of `includepdf`

Tags: macros, pdfpages

Consider the `\includepdf` macro from the `pdfpages` package. If I do

```
\includepdf[pages=1-]{blank.pdf}
```

there is no problem. However, if I do

```
\def\foo{{1-}}
\includepdf[pages=\foo]{blank.pdf}
```

I get the error

> ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

I earlier thought that the problem was that `\includepdf` wasn't expanding the macro argument to `pages`, but now I'm wondering if that is indeed the case. Because if I try

```
\includepdf[pages=\expanded{\foo}]{blank.pdf}
```

it makes no visible difference.

I've tried running with `\tracingmacros=1` and it looks like in both cases `\foo` at least gets expanded, but it's unclear what goes wrong after that. MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tracingmacros=1
\def\foo{{1-}}
\includepdf[pages=\foo]{blank.pdf}
% \includepdf[pages=\expanded{\foo}]{blank.pdf}
\tracingmacros=0
\end{document}
```

And here is part of the `\tracingmacros=1` output corresponding to the version with `\expanded`, namely

```
\includepdf[pages=\foo]{blank.pdf}
```

Output follows:

```
\foo ->{1-}

\AM@trim@spacei #1->\AM@trim@spaceii #1 \END 
#1<-{1-}

\AM@trim@spaceii #1 #2\END ->#1
#1<-1-
#2<-

\AM@checkinteger #1->\ifcat _\ifnum 9<1#1_\else A\fi \AM@integertrue \else \AM@
integerfalse \fi 
#1<-\AM@tempi 

\AM@tempi ->1-

\AM@integertrue ->\let \ifAM@integer \iftrue 

\AM@checkpagenumber #1->\ifnum #1>\AM@pagecount \relax \ifthenelse {\boolean {A
M@pkg@draft} \and \boolean {AM@survey}}{}{\PackageError {pdfpages} {Page #1 of 
`\AM@currentdocname ' does not exist} {You have set a wrong page number in the 
`pages' option. Document \MessageBreak `\AM@currentdocname ' does not have #1 p
ages.}}\fi 
#1<-\AM@tempi 

\AM@tempi ->1-

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again>
```

As can be seen, `\foo` does get expanded in this case.

Related question earlier asked by me: 
["Passing arguments using pgfkeys to a macro for including PDF files, using pdfpages"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/500305/3406).

Comment: Not tested, but the problem probably is due to the extra set of braces. Possibly in an early stage of processing, the package tries to search for a `-`, which it doesn't find because it's hidden between `{...}`. Then when checking the value of the page it assumes there is no `-` and tries to do `\ifnum 1->\AM@pagecount`, which is invalid. Probably if you remove the extra set of braces it will work.

Comment: Values to keys are generally not expanded; the macros for detecting a range require the hyphen to be “visible” to begin with.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It does the same thing without the braces. I could remove the braces if you want.

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by a "visible" hyphen? And if the issue is that the keys are not expanded, why doesn't  `\expanded` work? Am I applying it incorrectly?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Because values are not expanded, so instead of `\foo` the macros for detecting a range see `\expanded{\foo}` which has no hyphen as well.

Comment: @egreg I see. So putting `\expanded` there doesn't help. I understand. But if the values are not expanded, why does `1-` show up in the output of `\tracingmacros=1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `pdfpages` examines the `pages` key, it does what's specified in its definition

```latex
\define@key{pdfpages}{pages}{\AM@CheckValue{pages}{#1}%
                             \def\AM@pagestemp{#1}}
```

The `\AM@CheckValue` part is not a problem, because of

```latex
 \def\AM@CheckValue#1#2{%
  \ifx\\#2\\\PackageError{pdfpages}
             {Option `#1' must have a non-empty value}%
  \fi
}
```

(well, `\PackageError` should have *three* arguments, so it's best not passing an empty value).

Then `\AM@pagestemp` is set to contain the value, in your case `\foo`; it is initialized to contain `1`.

After that, `\expandafter\AM@readlist\expandafter{\AM@pagestemp}` is called, which becomes

```latex
\AM@readlist{\foo}
```

This is a macro that splits the argument at commas and each item is passed to `\AM@checkrange` by

```latex
\AM@checkrange#1-\END
```

In your case, `#1` is `\foo`. The macro is defined by

```latex
\def\AM@checkrange#1-#2\END{...}
```

and `#2` being empty means that no hyphen is present in the current item. But the macro also does

```latex
\edef\AM@tempi{\AM@trim@space{#1}}
```

so, in your case, `\AM@tempi` gets to contain `1-`; however, the expected value is an integer, which `1-` isn't. Error.

You can add to your document

```latex
\makeatletter
\define@key{pdfpages}{pages}{\AM@CheckValue{pages}{#1}%
                             \edef\AM@pagestemp{#1}}
\makeatother
```

but don't blame me if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. But shouldn't this just work?

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, why? The package author decided not to support macros in the value of the key `pages`.